# How can I write to a program after executing it in a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, runas

I need to build a bat file to run the `Runas` command.

Here is my command

```
Runas /user:Administrator "psexec \\\\***.***.***.*** -accepteula -i -u **** -p **** \"C:\\Program Files\\****\\setup.bat\""
```

When this is ran I am prompt for the password in the command line.

`Enter the password for Administrator:`

How can I write a bat file that enters the password: `password` into the prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Why doesn't the RunAs program accept a password on the command line?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx)

> The RunAs program demands that you type the password manually. Why
>   doesn't it accept a password on the command line?
>
> This was a conscious decision. If it were possible to pass the
>   password on the command line, people would start embedding passwords
>   into batch files and logon scripts, which is laughably insecure.
>
> In other words, the feature is missing to remove the temptation to use
>   the feature insecurely.

In short, your batch program will not be able to do it easily.  There are third party utilities that will actually assert themselves to a higher level of authentication and then call your scripts, essentially running them as administrator.

Some cost money, some are free, I don't have enough experience with any of them to tell you either way on their quality.